# How does Ruby's handling of socket output streams differ from Java's?

Tags: java, python, ruby, sockets

I have a Python server that listens for json requests. The "receiving" section of the code looks like this:

```
while True:
    next_message = conn.recv(1024)
    response = Foo.do_some_stuff(next_message)
    conn.send(response)
```

I built a Sinatra application that uses the Python API.

```
client = TCPSocket.new("localhost", 5000)
client.puts("foobar")
response = client.gets
```

All of the above code functions perfectly. Now, I'm doing something similar with some Java code.

```
Socket client = new Socket("localhost", 5000);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new client.getOutputStream(), true);
out.println("foobar");
String response = in.readLine();
```

The problem is that this code works for the first request, but on subsequent requests the Python server hangs, still waiting for the message. My question is what is the Ruby implementation of output stream appending to the message to signal the message's end that the Java implementation isn't?

Relevant details:
I'm using the Google Gson package in the Java code to create Json objects that I send to the Python server.
I'm using auto-flush on the PrintWriter.

I read that perhaps subsequent requests alter the size of the data being sent to the Python server - because of the underlying TCP protocol, and that the Python socket will keep listening until the connection ends or it's read 1024 bytes. This would make sense, except that the Ruby implementation works perfectly.

I've been digging through Java, Python, and Ruby docs for the past two days trying to figure this out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like a buffering issue.  Have you tried flushing the output?

Comment: Yes, I tried flushing the output.